# Memory error when trying to change Apache Tomcat port from 8080 to 80

Tags: apache, tomcat, port

I'm trying to get my installation of Tomcat on a VPS to run on port 80 instead of 8080, but when I edit the settings for the server.xml file in my Tomcat directory, and try to restart Tomcat, I'm getting this error:

> Jan 23, 2012 9:55:46 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>   SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint java.net.SocketException: Cannot
>   allocate memory
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:202)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:158)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1014)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413) Jan 23,
>   2012 9:55:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load SEVERE:
>   Catalina.start LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization
>   failed: java.net.SocketException: Cannot allocate memory
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1016)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Not really sure what that means... Does it mean I don't have enough memory? Are there alternative ways to get Tomcat to run on port 80?

Edit: Here is the output when I type in free -m:

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:   1024        748        275          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:   748        275
Swap:   0          0          0
```

Comment: something else already binded to port 80? check netstat

Comment: I have apache2 running, but when I close apache2 I still get the same errors.

Comment: Try port 81 or 89 just to see what happens.  Also, you can see what ports are in use using the netstat -a command.  If you hate command line tools, try TCPView.

Comment: Same thing happens with port 81. I used netstat and it doesn't look like anything is using port 81. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Ubuntu Linux. Maybe there's a problem with root access?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `free -m`.

Comment: Added output of free -m. I don't get why Tomcat won't work on another port if it works fine on port 8080...

Comment: This is probably a spurious error message. The root cause is probably that Tomcat is (appropriately) running as an unprivileged user trying to bind to a privileged port. The OS won't allow that and therefore can't bind to the socket. But it's strange to see it expressed as "memory allocation error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue with Tomcat on OpenVZ using authbind to run on port 80. I solved it by switching from OpenJDK to Sun Java.

Comment: How do I know if I'm running OpenJDK or Sun Java? Sorry, I'm not really an expert here...

Comment: "java -version" will tell you the runtime used

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I got Tomcat running on port 80. I had no idea that switching from OpenJDK to Sun Java would fix it... You're a lifesaver haha

Comment: An alternative solution is to reduce the memory allocated to Tomcat (the -Xmx parameter). On my system if I reduce the maximum heap size by about 70M Tomcat can be started with OpenJDK. You can also disable authbind and use iptable instead to redirect the ports, this will allow you to increase the maximum heap size by a factor 2 (because authbind forks the process and OpenVZ doesn't support memory overcommit, you can't exceed half of the available memory with -Xmx)